# code behind with postback url

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postbackurl

I try to make postpackurl in code behind so that I can send the code but my issue is when I click the button its keep it in the same page .

my question is how I can make the postbackurl directly go to next page?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
response.redirect("frmdefault.aspx")
```

in your button click code.

Comment: this code is note useful i try it but not post the form content in other page i use button.postbackurl = "pagename.aspx"
i use it with form that have text box and dropbox and i will post it in the page that accept only post method

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net `Button` Has property named `postbackurl` which you can set postbackurl:

```
<asp:button id="Button2"
  text="Post value to another page" 
  postbackurl="Button.PostBackUrlPage2cs.aspx" 
  runat="Server">
</asp:button>
```

Comment: this code is note useful i try it but not post the form content in other page i use button.postbackurl = "pagename.aspx"
i use it with form that have text box and dropbox and i will post it in the page that accept only post method

Answer (score 0):

In the ASPX file add the below Script:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SomeMethod() {
    window.location.reload("nextpage.aspx");
    return false;
 }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return SomeMethod();"/>
```

When the user clicks on the button1 the nextpage.aspx page will be executed and no postback will happen on the current page

Comment: this code is note useful i try it but not post the form content in other page i use button.postbackurl = "pagename.aspx"
i use it with form that have text box and dropbox and i will post it in the page that accept only post method